# mirror image in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to mirror an image in python  but this error occur

```
Exception has occurred: IndexError
index -751 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 750
File "D:\PART 1\Miror.py", line 20, in <module>
d=img.item(i,mn,0)
```

this is my code

```
img = cv2.imread('D:\\PART 1\\gwk.jpg')

tinggi = img.shape[0]
lebar  = img.shape[1]
brightness = 100
nm=int(tinggi-1)
mn=int(lebar-1)
lebarBaru= int(lebar/2)
tinggiBaru= int(tinggi/2)
for i in np.arange(tinggiBaru):
for j in np.arange(lebarBaru):
    a=img.item(i,j,0) 
    b=img.item(i,j,1) 
    c=img.item(i,j,2) 
    d=img.item(i,mn,0) 
    e=img.item(i,mn,1) 
    f=img.item(i,mn,2) 
    img.itemset((i,j,0),d)
    img.itemset((i,j,1),e)
    img.itemset((i,j,2),f)
    img.itemset((i,mn,0),a)
    img.itemset((i,mn,1),b)
    img.itemset((i,mn,2),c)
    mn-=1
```

I want to mirror an image in python without using OpenCV function for mirroring an image

Comment: Use [ImageOps.mirror()](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/PIL/ImageOps.html#mirror) of pillow to create a mirror image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just invert the direction of one (or both if you like) dimensions of the image array.

Example with `imageio`, but should work the same with similar image arrays, too, like e.g. in `opencv`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import imageio
im = imageio.imread('imageio:chelsea.png') 

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 3, sharey=True)

axs[0].imshow(im)
axs[1].imshow(im[:, ::-1, :])
axs[2].imshow(im[::-1, :, :])
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for you answer but i don't want to use any library func to make it work, and i already solve it thank you

Comment: There's no usage of a library function - just indexing an array `[:, ::-1, :]`...

Answer (score 4):

If you're willing to use NumPy (OpenCV uses NumPy arrays for storing images), use it's [`flip`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html) method. Otherwise, you can also just use the underlying array indexing using `::-1` notation.

Here's an example for mirroring in x direction (flip horizontally), y direction (flip vertically), and both directions (flip horizontally and vertically):

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read input image
img = cv2.imread('path/to/your/image.png')

# Mirror in x direction (flip horizontally)
imgX = np.flip(img, axis=1)
# imgX = imgX = img[:, ::-1, :]

# Mirror in y direction (flip vertically)
imgY = np.flip(img, axis=0)
# imgY = img[::-1, :, :]

# Mirror in both directions (flip horizontally and vertically)
imgXY = np.flip(img, axis=(0, 1))
# imgXY = img[::-1, ::-1, :]

# Outputs
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.imshow('imgX', imgX)
cv2.imshow('imgY', imgY)
cv2.imshow('imgXY', imgXY)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

(Exemplary input and outputs are omitted here...)

Hope that helps!

Comment: thank you for you answer but i don't want to use any library func to make it work, and i already solve it thank you